# Erlang exception error using BIF and lists:maps

Tags: list, exception, dictionary, erlang, normalize

Our task was to write a function normalize/1 which divides each element in the list my max element.

Here's my code so far (instead of my own written function, I used built in one to find max):

```
normalize(List) -> 
    Z = lists:max(List),
    [ X / Z  || X  <- List].
```

Now I have to write a function called normalize2 which does the same as normalize/1 but uses lists:map/2

```
normalize2(List) -> lists:map(fun normalize/1, List).
```

Terminal shows this:

test3:normalize2([1,2,3,5]).
** exception error: no function clause matching lists:max(1) (lists.erl, line 313)
     in function  test3:normalize/1 (test3.erl, line 85)
     in call from lists:map/2 (lists.erl, line 1224)

UPDATE:

Heres find_max/1:

```
find_max([T]) ->
    T;
find_max([H,H1|T]) when H > H1->
    find_max([H,T]);
find_max([_H,H1|T])->
    find_max([H1|T]).
```

If I used ^ find_max, terminal shows me:

test3:normalize2([1,2,3,5]).
** exception error: no function clause matching test3:find_max(1) (test3.erl, line 137)
     in function  test3:normalize/1 (test3.erl, line 84)
     in call from lists:map/2 (lists.erl, line 1224)

Line 137 is  find_max([T]) -> T;
Line 84 is Z = find_max(List),

Comment: If I used my own find_max/1 function in normalize/1, it shows me the same error, but instead of "no function clause matching lists:max(1)" it is no function clause matching lists:max(1,0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lists:max return max value from a list. It means argument of this function must be list.

When you call lists:map it means -- apply some function ('normailze' in your case) to each list item. But List items are integers. That is why the line  `Z=lists:max(List)` throws an exception (variable List is not list actually).

you can use lists:map as replacement of list comprehension. Kind of

```
normalize2(List) -> Z = lists:max(List), lists:map( fun(X) -> X/Z end, List).
```

Comment: If my input is [1,2,3,4] and I used a find_max/1, it gives me an answer like [4].

If I used that on normalize2 which I wrote above, I get this in terminal:
test3:normalize2([1,2,3,4]).
** exception error: no function clause matching test3:'-normalize/1-lc$^0/1-0-'(1) (test3.erl, line 86)
     in function  lists:map/2 (lists.erl, line 1224)

Comment: 1) what is find_max? 2) how did you use it? 3) it would be better if you provide the whole test3.erl

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I wish I could vote up your answer, but I dont have enough reputation points yet. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already figured out how to use a list comprehension in `normalize/1`, there is probably no point to write a "different" solution using `lists:map/2`.

Make sure to develop a mental reflex to always, instantly replace any use of `lists:map/2` with a beautiful list comprehension!

Comment: Why is that? Is it because its easier to read a bit or am I missing some information?

Comment: No other reason, indeed. `lists:map/2` is equivalent to the comprehension and lets you avoid writing the anonymous function.